# Iphone 4 won't update past a 7.1.2

Tags: iphone

I have a IPhone 4  model number A1349 an it won't update past a 7.1.2 it says my software is up to date but I know the latest software is at the least a 8.4. 
Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What have you tried? Are you looking for Apple's page of what hardware supports iOS 9.2.1 or is there something else you don't know.

Answer (score 9):

The latest iOS version supported by iPhone 4 is 7.1.2. There is no official way to install iOS 8 or newer on older iDevices.

You can find a compatability list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#Highest_version_of_iOS_supported).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but iOS 9 isn't supported on iPhone 4.

As you can see at the bottom of this page, the oldest supported iPhone is the iPhone 4s.

http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/

iOS 8 isn't even available for iPhone 4. As you can see here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/iOS_8#Supported_devices

The last supported OS is iOS 7.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried many times to install/update my iPhone 4 by computer, laptop, etc. All of those tries did not work, because the other updates cannot be supported by the iPhone 4 for example; iPhone 4's screen is too small for the updates , some apps might have more GB which your iPhone 4 might have 32 GB or less which is not enough for the other apps in the update. Also that's why you can't download some apps for your phone.

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted? Because the user is no native speaker? So am I! Everything the user here describes is true in some way and for the language barrier and the fact the user is not _exactly_ describing the problem you are downvoting. Come on...

Comment: This answer doesn't correctly state the actual reason: because iOS after 7.1.2 specifically simply does not support the iPhone 4. It's not because of the screen size or storage, because a 16 GB iPhone 4S with the same screen can be upgraded to iOS 9.x.